# Обучение сверточной искусственной нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Доброго всем времени суток! 
В процессе работы столкнулся с созданием сверточной нейронной сети на базе библиотеки Keras. Задача показалась поначалу простой, но уже на стадии проектирования вызвала ряд вопросов. 
В общем, перейду к сути.
Дано: база изображений листов растений.
Необходимо обучить СНС распознавать лист и отличать его от любого другого объекта на изображении. Стоит оговориться, что изображения простые - на них только один объект.
Т.е. фактически, на вход - изображение, на выходе - True или False (binary classification). Если с кодом проблем никаких, то к обучению есть вопросы. Могу ли я обучать нейросеть только на одном наборе данных? По идее, она же должна выделить признаки объекта. Как альтернатива, я думал о наборе cifar, но все же, наверно есть иной способ. 
Заранее благодарю за оказанную помощь и уделе́нное внимание!

Comment: Что значит один набор данных? Если речь идёт о нескольких тысячах фотографий, то это совершенно нормально. Я думаю стоило бы привести в вопросе код программы. Ещё неплохо было бы уточнить сам вопрос...

Comment: На одном наборе данных... Немного не так, как хотел выразился. Если обучить нейросеть только одному признаку - т.е. чтобы на лист растения она выдавала выше 0.5 (sigmoid), она будет выдавать значение ниже 0.5 для изображений не содержащих признака при этом не будучи обученной признакам других объектов.

Comment: Просто, никогда не сталкивался с примерами подобной задачи. Обычно, отличают что-то от чего-то. Т.е. цифры друг от друга, котов от собак и т.д. А, допустим, один какой-то объект от всего остального - такого не видел.

Comment: Это стандартная задача. Задачи мультиклассовой классификации можно рассматривать как набор бинарных  классификаций для каждого отдельного класса. На выходном слое NN в случае бинарной классификации будет один нейрон, а вслучае K классов - K нейронов с вероятностью принадлежности образца данному классу...

Comment: Это ясно. Нужен ли еще один набор данных, чтобы фактически научить нейросеть выдавать на этих данных False? Т.е. не возбуждать нейрон. Прошу прощения за такое ломанное объяснение.

Comment: я думаю в наборе данных должны присутствовать листы других растений тоже, иначе может случиться, что ваша сеть будет классифицировать все зеленое с похожей формой листа как это конкретное растение...

Comment: Нет, подборка очень большая. Порядка 50 тысяч изображений. Да и прежде, чем классифицировать растение по многим классам: вид растения; его болезнь, надо хотя бы определить, растение ли это. Значит, вы утверждаете, что я могу использовать только набор листов растений и все и если я, скажем, подам на вход изображение с самолетом, нейрон не возбудится. Спасибо, я понял идею. Благодарю вас за помощь!